# Generating two lists in a single iteration of a large XML document

Tags: java, xml, list, loops, return

Given a list of `ID`s, I need to iterate over a large OSM (Open Street Map) file ([example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23616645/Geosprocket_Share/btv_prints_011513.osm)), and collect two separate types of info for the corresponding nodes: coordinates, and user names (not important for them to be associated once I extract it - i.e. I don't need to know which user corresponds to which coordinates)

That is, I need to check each node in the file to see if they match one of the ID's in the list I'm given, and if they do, I want to keep the coordinates (latitude and longitude) and the user info (the person who contributed the node) and return the data.

In Java, I can't return two separate lists in a single method. In a world of no constraints, I would iterate over the document twice - the first time to get coordinates data, and the second time to get the user data. 
However, this is not practical in this case because the OSM files I'm dealing with can be huge - often in the gigabytes!

So my question is, what's the best way to iterate ONCE but generate multiple lists of data you want to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a list of objects where each object contains the coordinates and user name. You can iterate over the response list of objects as many times as you need or retrieve the data you need in one pass over the objects in the list.

Comment: Where this class be created? As an inner class?

Comment: If you need to share it between 2 classes, say one class reads the OSM data and returns the list to another class for processing, then I'd do a regular class (in it's own source file). If you're doing all the processing in one class, I'd just use an inner class.